# How to generate circles distributed randomly without overlap?

Tags: algorithm, random

I need to generate a graph that a number of points with different radius are randomly located in the canvas without overlapping.

For example,
Inputs are canvas size {w:1000, h:1000} and

```
{
    {num:40, radius:30}, // 40 points with radius=30
    {num:100, radius:2}, // 100 points with radius=12
    .....
}
```

And output is that these points random positioned in the canvas but there is no overlap.

I want to be able to visualize the graph, so I used jquery to write the code, but didn't work out.

Any algorithm or tools you can recommend? 
Thanks guys!

Comment: No code: no language. An algorithm is an algorithm: no language. (Also, a point as no size; a circle has a radius.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ideas for an algorithm for random distribution of circles in a square](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946152/ideas-for-an-algorithm-for-random-distribution-of-circles-in-a-square)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946152/ideas-for-an-algorithm-for-random-distribution-of-circles-in-a-square , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002407/placing-random-circles-without-overlap-and-without-using-brute-force?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004992/algorithm-to-calculate-the-positions-of-random-circles-so-they-dont-overlap?lq=1

Comment: http://www.paulbourke.net/texture_colour/randomtile/