# Create a list of N random (x,y,z) points that are at least a distance r away from each other

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of N random (x,y,z) points using python, in a way that each point is at least a distance r away from any other point.

I'm super new to programming and so far I'm only able to generate x, y, and z separately (then put together) by using

```
import random 
def RandX(start, end, num): 
    res = [] 

    for j in range(num): 
        res.append(random.randint(start, end)) 

    return res 
num = N
start = 0
end = 100
print(RandX(start, end, num))
```

but I have no idea how to control or check the positions of the points(x, y, z) so that the points are a distance away from each other.

Comment: First of all these are not `(x, y, z)` points. you're creating a list of `N` numbers. So you need to make that a triplet. Second, about the distance, use the known formula for distance between points and every time youtry to add a point, make sure the distance with the other ones is fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499139/how-can-i-set-a-minimum-distance-constraint-for-generating-points-with-numpy-ran

Comment: Possoin disc sampling fits the bill here: https://scipython.com/blog/poisson-disc-sampling-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. (It can be optimised but should serve you as very first version)

```
from collections import namedtuple
import random
import math

Point = namedtuple('Point', ' x y z')

MIN = 0
MAX = 1000


def fill_points_list(points, number_of_required_points, min_distance):
    def _get_distance(p1, p2):
        return math.sqrt(sum([(a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(p1, p2)]))

    while len(points) < number_of_required_points:
        temp = Point(random.randint(MIN, MAX), random.randint(MIN, MAX), random.randint(MIN, MAX))
        count = 0
        for p in points:
            if _get_distance(temp, p) > min_distance:
                count += 1
            else:
                break
        if len(points) == count:
            points.append(temp)


number_of_required_points = 9
min_distance = 51
points = []

fill_points_list(points, number_of_required_points, min_distance)

print(points)
```

output

[`Point(x=771, y=590, z=226), Point(x=385, y=835, z=900), Point(x=551, y=294, z=800), Point(x=824, y=306, z=333), Point(x=892, y=548, z=879), Point(x=520, y=660, z=384), Point(x=409, y=193, z=331), Point(x=411, y=706, z=300), Point(x=272, y=116, z=719)]`

Answer (score 1):

To check the distance between two points (x,y,z) and (a,b,c) (stored as tuples), you can try:

```py
def distance(p1,p2):
    d=0
    for i in range(3):
        d+=(p1[i]-p2[i])**2
    return d**(1/2)
```

Once you generate xyz randomly, you can set the following:

```py
p1=x,y,z
p2=a,b,c
```

If your numbers are not too large, while this is inefficient, you can generate random numbers until they satisfy the distance condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution: all we need is a distance function and a loop to generate random points and check for minimum distance criteria within our already-generated list:

```
def dist(new_point, points, r_threshold):
    for point in points:
        dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(new_point-point)))
        if dist < r_threshold:
            return False
    return True


def RandX(N, r_threshold):
    points = []
    scope = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
    while len(points) < N:
        new_point = np.random.choice(scope, 3)
        if dist(new_point, points, r_threshold):
            points.append(new_point)
    return points
```

For example:

```
RandX(5, 4)
[array([3.5, 2.6, 7.6]),
 array([9.9, 0.1, 7.2]),
 array([4. , 2.8, 0.3]),
 array([0.2, 7.4, 5.1]),
 array([7.4, 6.3, 5.2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to generate randomly a number of points, and then filter them based on the distance criteria. The `numpy` and `sklearn` packages can be helpful make the process more efficient. You could imagine something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

r = 2

# Generate 100 points (3-tuples) between 0 and 10
points = np.random.randint(0,100,[1000,3])

# Pairwise distances between points
distances = euclidean_distances(points)

# "Remove" distance to itself by setting to a distance of r+1 (to discard it later)
distances += np.identity(len(distances)) * (r+1)

# Retrieve the distance to the closest point
min_dist = np.min(distances,axis=1)

# Filter your set of points
filtered_points = points[min_dist>r]
```

This should run pretty fast.